# Unable to run chrome with Testcafe on macOS

Tags: macos, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have been trying without success to run tests on chrome using Testcafe in MacOS. I have generated all the certificates required but when launching chrome with testcafe it reports ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH. Below are the arguments I am passing -

```
yarn run testcafe --hostname localhost --ssl 'pfx = testingdomain.pfx;rejectunasuthorized=true;--ssl key = testingdomain.key;cert=testingdomain.crt' "chrome --use-fake-ui-for-media-stream --allow-insecure-localhost --allow-running-insecure-content" e2e/testmac.js --live
```

When I remove  loading PFX cert and run below, I am able to get to the webpage, but cant access mic and camera. My command to maximzie browser window also does not work

```
yarn run testcafe --hostname localhost "chrome --use-fake-ui-for-media-stream --allow-insecure-localhost --allow-running-insecure-content --live" e2e/testmac.js --ssl 'key=testingdomain.key;cert=testingdomain.crt' --live
```

My simple test -

```
import { Selector, ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';
fixture`Audio Configuration Combination`.page`http://XXX.XXX.XXXXXX/sandbox/index.html`;
test('Launch SDK,', async (browser) => {
   await browser.getCurrentWindow().maximizeWindow().wait(100000);
 });
```

I have problems only on mac. Same setup is working fine on windows. I need to access mic and camera and so passing in "--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream". But I dont see a camera preview. Passing in "--use-fake-device-for-media-stream" loads up fake devices which is something I dont need.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this comment](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/3532#issuecomment-470167128) on GitHub, it should be sufficient to use either of the two approaches to mock user media, not necessarily both. If you specify `testcafe --hostname localhost`, you shouldn't need to specify `--ssl` at all.

I ran the following test from the GitHub discussion mentioned above on macOS:

**mock-media-test.js**

```js
fixture `WebRTC`
    .page`https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/canvas/`;

test(`test`, async t => t.wait(30000));
```

I used the following command:

```sh
testcafe "chrome --use-fake-ui-for-media-stream" mock-media-test.js --hostname localhost
```

The test ran as expected, and the page displayed the stream from my camera. The `--use-fake-device-for-media-stream` flag worked for me as well.